# Variables in Spark-sql Data-bricks to dynamically assign values

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

```
Declare @var INT = 10
SELECT * from dbo.school where class = @var
```

This is how we declare in SQL.
How do I do the same in Spark SQL in data bricks?

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  val i = 10
  val sqlS = s"SELECT * from dbo.school where class = $i"
  val df = spark.sql(sqlS)
```